# Get the object key name in JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

Am having an object like:

```
var myObj={
    id: 1,
    name: "John",
    parentName: "Peter"
}
```

But while processing this JSON I'm comparing with some logic where I'm not able to get the key name to be compared since I'm assigning the key name to be compared to another variable:

Example:

This is the logic:

If I want to get the value of `parentName` say "Peter".My logic compares by having the parentName stored in another variable say `dummyVariable`.If so I'm fetching the value of parent Name like

```
 var dummyVariable=parentName;

 var parentValu=myObj.dummyVariable; //which leads to a undefined state .
```

How can I get the value of parentName if I use a different variable,in this case dummyVariable?

Comment: Use bracket notation `var parentValu=myObj[dummyVariable]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is this:

```
var myObj={
    id: 1,
    name: "John",
    parentName: "Peter"
}
```

Then:

```
var result = myObj['parentName'];  
// result now equals "Peter"
```

or

```
var key = 'parentName';
var result = myObj[key];
// result now equals "Peter"
```

Comment: What can be done if the object is dynamic

Answer (score 0):

the approach you might want to try is myObj[dummyVariable]